# Find a value for the match in string in python

Tags: python

Basically, I want to do following, I have a file full of such rows

`Queue SIZE="1024" QID="8" TYPE="IOSQ" ADDRESS="0x218464000"`

I need to do following,

`If("IOSQ" in line):` then capture the value of Address which is `"0x218464000"`

How do I script this in Python?

Comment: where does this  `Queue SIZE="1024" QID="8" TYPE="IOSQ" ADDRESS="0x218464000"` line came from ? are you reading it from a file ? where is your piece of work ? Try to show some code , people would be glad to help you out

Comment: Turns out, editing my answer removed your "accept answer". Anyway, i added some explanation on how each part of the reg ex works, so that you can use it on your own later on. You may also take a look at the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions.

```
import re

my_string = 'Queue SIZE="1024" QID="8" TYPE="IOSQ" ADDRESS="0x218464000"'

pattern = re.compile(r'IOSQ.*?ADDRESS="(\dx\d+)')    
matches = re.findall(pattern, my_string)

print(matches)
```

The pattern is `r'IOSQ.*?="(\dx\d+)`. `r'something'` is a raw string, you should use this always. Then `IOSQ` requires exact match of those letters. `.*?` means *match any character*, from 0 to as few as possible (until a full match is found). Parenthesis makes `findall` return only the contents of the parenthesis. `\d` means digits 0 to 9. `+` means one or more of the previous character being matched.

Comment: Perhaps a more appropriate regex: `re.search('ADDRESS="(.*?)"', my_string).group(1)`

Comment: @JonClements You are correct on `ADDRESS=" `, but i assume from his question that `IOSQ` must be part of the match.

Answer (score 0):

If the data are well-formatted, you might consider this:

```
lst = 'Queue SIZE="1024" QID="8" TYPE="IOSQ" ADDRESS="0x218464000"'.split()

def make_dict(lst):
    return dict([tuple(item.split('=')) for item in lst])

dic = {}
dic[lst[0]] = make_dict(lst[1:])
print dic
```

Which gives:

```
{'Queue': {'QID': '"8"', 'ADDRESS': '"0x218464000"', 'TYPE': '"IOSQ"', 'SIZE': '"1024"'}}
```

Then you can access the value `dic[lst[0]].get('ADDRESS', 'no address').strip('"')`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `shlex.split` to standardise the data (quotes etc..), then build a dict of key=value, then take the address (or blank) if the type is "IOSQ" otherwise leave the address as blank, eg:

```
import shlex

s = 'Queue SIZE="1024" QID="8" TYPE="IOSQ" ADDRESS="0x218464000"'
d = dict(el.partition('=')[::2] for el in shlex.split(s))
# {'QID': '8', 'TYPE': 'IOSQ', 'ADDRESS': '0x218464000', 'SIZE': '1024', 'Queue': ''}
address = d.get('ADDRESS', '') if d.get('TYPE') == 'IOSQ' else ''
# '0x218464000'
```

This has the advantage that you're not relying on the ordering of key="something" in the text being the same and you can always access values for other keys if needs be later.